# Anthology movie containing three stories, including one about a fat man who wanted to lose weight, and became as light as a feather while still fat

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to find a movie which was about 3 short stories. The first was about a fat man who wanted to lose weight and then became light as a feather and flew like a balloon. And still he was fat.

The second story was about a man who wanted to be fast. And then he became so fast that no one could see him and he died in few days.

The third story was about a man who wanted to have longer hair and then his hair wouldn`t stop growing constantly.

I think there is also a book with those short stories but I don`t know the name of the book or the movie. The stories are situated in retro times, like maybe year 1920.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this movie, and when do you think it was made? Also, what language did you watch it in?

Comment: The third story reminds me of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_Bags_(film)#%22Hair%22

Comment: @Thea Atanasova - If anyone correctly identifies the movie/series you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if the only answers posted are incorrect, please indicate that with a comment so we know to keep looking. (You can leave comments by clicking on the `Add a comment` link below your question.) Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

This is the mini-series [The Infinite Worlds of H. G. Wells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Infinite_Worlds_of_H._G._Wells).  It was 6 total hours, each hour adapting one of Wells' short stories.  They are presented as if Wells himself encountered the events.

I believe you are remembering only 2 of the six:

From the Wikipedia summaries (emphases mine):

"The New Accelerator"

> Wells and Jane thus begin to investigate, finding clues that lead them to a surprising discovery: the existence of an **"accelerating drug"**, invented by Mark Radcliffe, another professor at the university, which allows people, for a short period of time, to be faster than sound.
>
> Found out the responsible for the accident that occurred to prof. Gibberne, Wells and Jane go to Radcliffe's laboratory, **seeing him disappear** before their eyes. It will be up to Wells and Gibberne to find out where Radcliffe has disappeared with his drug, facing a sad reality: perhaps the accelerating drug is not only a step forward for humanity, but also **a sacrifice of one's existence**.

and

"The Truth About Pyecraft"

> A friend of [his], Mark Pattison, on advice of a colleague, visits a shady pharmacist and obtains a miraculous cure for his baldness. Showing Albert the **quick regrowth of his hair**, he convinces him to get a similar potion to cure his fatness.
>
> When Albert does not show up for work or at the club for two days, Wells goes to his place and finds him **floating** on the ceiling: his wish to **"lose weight" has been interpreted too literally**. Wells and Jane help Albert to walk again on the ground by putting lead in his clothes. Visiting the club, he finds Pattison hidden in the bathroom and victim of the same cure he requested: **his hair keeps growing at high rate all over his body**.

The other stories are:

- "The Queer Story of Brownlow's Newspaper"
- "The Crystal Egg"
- "The    Remarkable Case of Davidson's Eyes"
- "The Stolen Bacillus"