# Help me identity some old Mini-Series or anthology. Includes Truth Serum, Mysterious Egg and superspeed

Tags: story-identification, tv

I want some help identifying an old tv-series that I saw years ago.

To be honest, I don't remember if it was a TV-Series, but it was played on a TV station in Europe. It was 2004 to 2008. That was when it was played, so I suspect (because it's pricey to rent the copyrights), it was **probably older, maybe pre 2000**?

It played from 18:00 to 01:00 or 02:00 in the night. Given that, there were multiple ads in between and even an one hour news section, so **I suspect the actual duration of the series to be from 3 and a half to 5 hours**.

Now, onto the plot, it consisted of multiple "smaller" stories. The stories I remember are the following:

- A scientist discovers a serum/drug, that when consumed, allowed him to gain *superspeed*. Everything around him was standing still. There were some people (students or family) that searched for him, but couldn't find him. After a while, they discover the drug he took, they take it too and experience a standing reality that nothing moves. They find him after some time and he is an old man now. He tells them that because he had too much of that drug, he spend so many years in a still world where nothing moved, but on normal time it was a day or two.
- A truth serum is accidentally poured into a local river of a town. Everyone gets it and now they can't lie. A very specific scene I still remember (because it was funny), was someone going to a grocery that had some fruit in the entrance and he asked someone who worked there "Hey, are these fruit fresh?". And the response was "Yes, but the fresh ones are the ones in the back, don't take from the front of the container".
- Another story that I don't remember much about, was about a mysterious (maybe it was glowing?) egg that someone found. Don't remember what hatched from it.
- Now, that's a BIG maybe, my memories might play games after close to 20 years, but I think there was another story about a utopia. Like a place where everything was awesome and everyone enjoyed their time there, but something happened that broke the "façade" of the place.

There might have been other stories. Those episodes, when they initially came out, probably were separate and played one each day. In the TV station that I watched them 20 something years back, they just put them all together.

The only other thing that I might remember is the title of the series. When something like

- The amazing stories of...
- The amazing world of...
- The stories of...
- The memories of...

Basically it was the narrator that "told" his stories to us, and his name was at the end.

Comment: An Outer Limits (1995) episode "In The Zone" has a similar plot to the super speed description.

Comment: Hi @Shawn, thanks for the suggestion. That's what ChatGPT told me too after prompting my question. I do not believe it's any episode of outer limits, but I will check again each plot and try to find the stories. Thanks again!

Comment: This is probably the series «The Infinite Worlds of H.G. Wells» episode 1 «The New Accelerator», episode 3 «The Crystal Egg» and episode 6 «The Stolen Bacillus». I saw those three episodes on tv in Norway in the 2000nds https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0280770/episodes/?ref_=tt_eps_sm

Comment: Here is the wikipedia entry for the episodes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Infinite_Worlds_of_H._G._Wells

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTFMG9rIavw&t=675s  At 18:33 You can watch the scene with the fresh fruits at the market.

Comment: @epsben - Is there a reason you've not posted this as an answer?

Comment: Possibly related [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/251621/anthology-movie-containing-three-stories-including-one-about-a-fat-man-who-want/251625#251625).

Comment: Sorry, was on mobile, then family stuff...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is  the series "The Infinite Worlds of H.G. Wells"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Infinite_Worlds_of_H._G._Wells

The first story is episode 1 "The New Accelerator".

(Here is the scene where they discover the scientist stuck in accelerated time)

The second story is episode 6 "The Stolen Bacillus".

(At 18:34 is the scene with the fruit stall)

The third story is episode 3 "The Crystal Egg".

(Here is the scene with the main characters studying the "egg" followed by the scene with the creature inside)

Comment: Unreal, found it after so much time. Thank you sooo much @epsben!

Comment: The episode «The new accelerator» made a deep impression on me as a child. It awakened my interest in H. G . Wells’ works.